# How to achieve this javascript effect?

Tags: javascript, ajax

On this website: when the user clicks "register now" along the top bar the screen goes dim and a box appears offering the registration form with recaptcha. I have a registration form with recaptcha working on my site and would like to copy the effect seen above.

Can anyone link me to a specific tutorial offering instructions or alternatively provide me with the code?

I am a novice javascript programmer.

Thanks if you can help me.

Comment: Am I missing something? Which website are you talking about?

Comment: You accidentally the website url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's couple of good plugins for that. If you use jQuery you can check [Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) and even [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) should probably be enough for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jQuery [effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/), in case you haven't heard of jQuery before, [here](http://www.authenticsociety.com/blog/jQueryPluginTutorial_Beginner) is a good introduction.

```
$('#register').click(function() {
  $('#topBar').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    // Some Code
  });
});
```

Comment: ahh - beat me to it while I was looking up the links ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The effect you are talking about is generally described as a "lightbox" - based on one of the earliest implementations (from what I remember). Check out [this page on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbox_(JavaScript)) and look about - the modal dialog implementation might be what you're talking about.

I'm pretty sure some of the standard frameworks like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and [MooTools](http://mootools.net) implement this (directly or via plugins).